# svg-android unresolved methods

Tags: android, svg

Im trying to use [svg-android](https://github.com/japgolly/svg-android)

I add this line to my gradle

`compile 'com.github.japgolly.android:svg-android:2.0.6`'

but, following the simple usage example show me unresolved method

```
Drawable drawable = svg.createDrawable();// createDrawable unresolved
```

Following [this](https://code.google.com/p/svg-android/wiki/Tutorial) example show me unresolved methods too

I Added the [jar](https://code.google.com/p/svg-android/downloads/detail?name=svg-android.jar) to libs

```
SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), R.raw.android); // getSVGFromResource Unresolved
imageView.setImageDrawable(svg.createPictureDrawable()); // createPictureDrawable Unresolved
```

Could not find a way to use this library.
Any idea?

Comment: On the main page of that library is clearly written: **Status: Unmaintained. Discontinued.** Try using another svg-android version. Or use `android-svg`.

Comment: Right! I updated my post. The second link I post point to android-svg. Following the Simple example still show me unresolved methods.

Comment: I used [svg-android (applantation flavour)](https://github.com/applantation/svg-android), which worked at the first trial.

Comment: Ok! Just Forget to add compile files('libs/svg-android.jar') after added the jar.  Seems to work. 'com.github.japgolly.android:svg-android:2.0.6' seems to be out of date. Thanks